# Ignore empty filter criteria in SUMPRODUCT formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula

```
  |      A      |      B      |      C      |          D        |     E
--|-------------|-------------|-------------|-------------------|---------------
1 | Product     |   Brand     |   Revenue   |  Filter Product   |   Product A
2 | Product A   |   Brand 1   |     500     |  Fitler Brand     |   Brand 1
3 | Product A   |   Brand 2   |     600     |  Result           |   500  
4 | Product B   |   Brand 2   |     400     |                   |
5 | Product C   |   Brand 3   |     350     |                   |
6 | Product C   |   Brand 1   |     800     |                   |
7 | Product C   |   Brand 1   |     700     |                   |
```

---

In `Cell E3` I want to sum the revenue in `Column C` based on the criterias that are entered in `Cell E1` and `Cell E2`. Therefore, I implemented this formula which works perfectly.

```
=SUMPRODUCT(($C$2:$C$7)*($A$2:$A$7=E1)*($B$2:$B$7=E2))
```

---

However, now I want to implement in the formula a logic that if `Cell E1` or `Cell E2` is empty those filters are ignored. 
For example if `Cell E1` is empty and `Cell E2="Brand 1"` the result would be `2.000 (500+800+700)`

Therefore, I tried to modify the formula like this:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(($C$2:$C$7)*($A$2:$A$7=IF(E1="","*",E1))*($B$2:$B$7=IF(E2="","*",E2)))
```

However, this formula gives me back `0` and not the expected `2.000`.

How do I need to adjust it to make it work?

Comment: What is your excel version?

Comment: I use Office365

Comment: SUMPRODUCT() takes empty cells as 0 in all the times I have used it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`=SUMPRODUCT(($C$2:$C$7)*(IF(E1="",1,($A$2:$A$7=E1))*(IF(E2="",1,$B$2:$B$7=E2))))`

Replaces the condition with `1` (all values) in case `E1` and/or `E2` is empty, using IF.

In Office 365 you could use this formula:

```
=IFERROR(SUM(FILTER(C2:C7,(IF(E1="",1,A2:A7=E1))*(IF(E2="",1,+B2:B7=E2)))),0)
```

Comment: When there is an if function in a sumproduct, dont you need to confirm the formula with Control + Shit + Enter?

Comment: Actually SUMPRODUCT is a formula that enforces array calculation, also in older versions. No need to confirm with `ctrl+shift+enter`

Comment: @P.b Do you have any idea for this as well: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75428596/ignore-empty-filter-criteria-in-countifs-formula

Comment: Just replied, lol

Comment: @P.b  Yes Sumproduct and a few other perform array like operations, however when they include an IF statement they sometimes need the control + shift + enter as well to work properly.  I only have 2013 so not sure if this has changed in office 365

Comment: If it works in 2013 it works in all versions. Office 365 no longer requires `ctrl+shift+enter` it defaults to array calculation

Comment: @Michi, you don't happen to be from Hamburg?