# Ignore empty filter criteria in COUNTIFS formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula

```
  |      A      |      B      |      C      |          D        |     E
--|-------------|-------------|-------------|-------------------|---------------
1 | Product     |   Brand     |   Revenue   |  Filter Product   |   Product C
2 | Product A   |   Brand 1   |     500     |  Fitler Brand     |   Brand 1
3 | Product A   |   Brand 2   |     600     |  Result           |   2  
4 | Product B   |   Brand 2   |     400     |                   |
5 | Product C   |   Brand 3   |     350     |                   |
6 | Product C   |   Brand 1   |     800     |                   |
7 | Product C   |   Brand 1   |     700     |                   |
```

In cell `E3` I want to count the products based on the criteria that are entered in cell `E1` and `E2`.

Therefore, I implemented this formula which works perfectly:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(COUNTIFS($A$2:$A$7;$E$1;$B$2:$B$7;$E$2))
```

However, now I want to implement in the formula a logic that if cell `E1` or `E2` is empty those filters are ignored.

For example if cell `E1` is empty and cell `E2="Brand 1"`, the result would be `3`.

With reference to the answer in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75425852/ignore-empty-filter-criteria-in-sumproduct-formula/75425995#75425995) I assume the solution looks something like this:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(COUNTIFS($A$2:$A$7;IF($E$1="";1;$A$2:$A$7);IF($E$2="";1;$B$2:$B$7)))
```

However, I have not been able to make the formula work correctly.

Do you have any idea how I have to modify it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
=IFERROR(ROWS(FILTER(C2:C7,(IF(E1="",1,A2:A7=E1))*(IF(E2="",1,+B2:B7=E2)))),0)
```

Using FILTER you can count the rows of the result. In case no matches from the values in `E1` or `E2` the filter and the count of rows will return an error, hence the `IFERROR(formula,0)`

*PS replacing ROWS with SUM is an alternative solution to your previous question.*

With SUMPRODUCT you could use something like this:

`=SUMPRODUCT((LEN(A2:A7)>0)*(IF(E1="",1,A2:A7=E1))*(IF(E2="",1,B2:B7=E2)))`